# How I can add values from my table without using update?

Tags: php, mysql

How I can add values to my mysql table with php without using update and only using select?

My table have a row with the name `sale`. How I can do this with php?

Thanks.

@EDIT:
One guy give me this but isn't working for me:

```
SELECT saldo + 50 as saldo FROM tabela;
```

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: `SELECT` is for selection, you can't alter or add data with a `SELECT` statement

Comment: But i want update my row, without using update, i edit my question with a code that on guy give me but dont work for me.

Comment: ["I" is always uppercase on English, questions end with a "?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370).

Answer (score 0):

Some code would be helpful, but you cannot add values into your MySQL table with using UPDATE, UPDATE is to UPDATE values.

```
UPDATE tbl SET sale = 10000 WHERE tbl_id=1;
```

To insert/add values, you have to use INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (sale) VALUES (10000);
```

You can use SELECT only if you are for example, pulling data from one table into your current one:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (sale) SELECT (sale_scores) FROM tbl2;
```

Or another way is to use SELECT INTO

```
SELECT * INTO tbl3 FROM tbl;
```

Comment: But i want update my row, without using update, i edit my question with a code that on guy give me but dont work for me.

Comment: You cannot update your row without using UPDATE, that's why SQL has UPDATE, to UPDATE rows.

Comment: I edited my ask with the string one guy send me. Check please.

Comment: SELECT saldo + 50 as saldo FROM tabela;

This isn't update inside SQL, that's just that it displays +50 to the 'saldo' you query from it. That doesn't save any data, it just displays it differently.

Comment: You can use that code, but that will keep the original data intact (without actually updating the rows, it just displays it like that).

Comment: What is the better solution for the page with receive a thousand of visits, and for not bug?

Comment: As Janno has said, if you need to update a row you need to run UPDATE within your MySQL query.

Comment: But he give me some suluttions what is better in your opinion?

Comment: I've added in an answer as to what I'd do but it all boils down to whats being updated, if it's a users row thats updating or a general one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE` which has the same syntax as `INSERT`,  but replaces the existing row at the coincidence of a unique key.

**Example**:

Table before:

`| id | name |
| -- | ---- |
|  1 | Nick |
|  2 | John |`

Run: `REPLACE table_name (id, name) VALUES (2, "Sam")`

Table after:

`| id | name |
| -- | ---- |
|  1 | Nick |
|  2 | Sam  |`

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: I put the code i have in my ask but dont work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use PDO with a simple UPDATE request and bind the params. I see no point in trying to get around using something that is already in place and works a treat.

Here's an example of what I'd do.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `saldo` = `saldo` + 50 WHERE `username` = :uname");
$stmt->bindParam(":uname",$username);
$stmt->execute();
```